# What can you do when nobody can answer your question?

Tags: discussion

On the 22nd of August, I asked [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61029/words-in-the-kagoshima-dialect). But no one's answered yet, and the system keeps on telling me to tae breathers and edit my questions in the meantime in spite of my 3 other questions being successfully answered and not being voted down.

What should I do?

Comment: what does "tae breathers"  mean?

Comment: To be fair, that question requires very specialist linguistic knowledge. You might have more luck contacting Japanese linguistics professors directly or doing a search for academic papers on Google scholar.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure if this is the right sort of answer per se...

but I think that's a pretty difficult question to answer and it could be the case that there is no person on the site who:

1. grasps your question's English sufficiently
2. knows the answer
3. Feels comfortable answering (maybe because they don't have good quality sources to cite?)

Everyone on the site is volunteering their time to help others and themselves understand Japanese better.

Also for a few of the others ones of yours that I scanned, you've accepted at least one answer that's just speculation rather than sourced.

So my advice would be to expect a question like that to take a while to find an answer. Have you tried searching for an answer to it in Japanese on say 知恵袋?

Answer (score 1):

Because it hasn't been mentioned, yet, but I think it deserves a mention to the question "What can you do when nobody answers your question?":

Once you have collected some reputation, you can **[start a bounty](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)**.

You can read all about bounties under the above link, but you're giving away your own reputation for adding visibility to your question and you can award the bounty to answers. My experience is that low value bounties (50-100 points) don't really gather that much attention and the bounty expires after about a week, so with a difficult question you might want to place a bounty strategically (for example, wait until you can start a higher bounty).